# Three columns in website layout without stacking

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, zurb-foundation

I'm building a new site and I want it to have 3 columns.  Something like span3, span6, span3.  When viewed on a mobile phone I would like only the middle (span6) column to be visible (with side scrolling required in order to see the outer columns).  Is this sort of behavior possible with either Twitter's Bootstrap or Zurb's Foundation?

**EDIT**
The least I need is that all 3 columns stay as columns.  I don't want them to stack on a smart phone.  I got it to work with Foundation and was wondering if there's a solution with Bootstrap.  Currently my Bootstrap code stacks all 3 columns?

**Foundation**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="small-3 large-3 columns">
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>
  <div class="small-6 large-6 columns">
    <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
  </div>
  <div class="small-3 large-3 columns">
    <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Bootstrap**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="span3">
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>
  <div class="span6">
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>
  <div class="span3">
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check out the off canvas slides for zurb foundation 3 here:

http://zurb.com/playground/off-canvas-layouts

I don't believe foundation or bootstrap support this out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it is not possible out of the box, basically because of the side scrolling condition. Not even with their responsive versions.